# LINQ group by and return all results

Tags: c#, linq

I have troubles finding the solution for this. I know it had a lot of topics here, but none of it (which I found) works for me.
So this is the question, I have this:

```
   List<Products> testList = new List<Products>();
```

This list have two fields, price and stock. I want to group stocks by some condition but still show all the results.
I'm grouping values like this:

```
  var stocks=testList.Where(item=> item.stock== "StocksFR1:").GroupBy(item=> item.stock);
```

This works just fine. But I want to iterate through all results, and I'm failing.
I have tried to do JOIN, but really don't know on which attribute I can join these values.
Anybody? Thanks!

Update: (Example of the input list:)

```
    Stock:        Price:
    StocksFR1:    14.55
    StocksFR1:    3.4
    StocksFRF:    1.1
    StocksFRA:    13.3
```

And with group, I want to have this output:

```
    Stock:        Price:
    StocksFR1:    14.55, 3.4
    StocksFRF:    1.1
    StocksFRA:    13.3
```

Comment: What exactly is "failing" when iterating through the results?

Comment: Why do you need `GroupBy`, After you filter `Where`, you will end up with just one group. May be you are only looking for  `var stocks=testList.Where(item=> item.stock== "StocksFR1:");` without group by

Comment: A `Where` clause will inherently *not* show "all the results." I'm also noticing that in your `Where` predicate, you're listing `item.stock == "StocksFR1:"`. Is that complete? It might well be, but are you sure you aren't looking for `item.stock.StartsWith("StocksFR1:")` or something to that effect?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Failing to show all results. I'm getting only these grouped values.

Comment: But you've explicitly limited the results using a `Where` clause.  Just take that out to include everything.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Yes, item.stock == "StocksFR1:" is complete.

Comment: as @recursive noted, you already limited with the `Where` clause. If you want everything grouped, get rid of it. Without knowing what the problem is that you are trying to solve its hard to give a concrete answer.

Comment: @recursive But I want to group only items with some stock name. That's why. I think I need here some join in other query, as I've read so far.

Comment: So you want to show all stocks, but only group some of them??? Thats a very odd thing to do...

Comment: Why do you have the `Where` clause if you don't only want those?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've updated question, you can see example. Maybe I didn't explained well in the begining. Thanks for all comments guys!

Comment: Based on your update, I'd say you need to get rid of the `Where`.  That's the only change you need.

Comment: @recursive THANKS a lot. That was it. I can't believe... And I wrote 101 query and join..

Comment: Thank you all for the contribution! It was really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, disregarding much of what you have and looking only at the example data, it seems like you want this:

```
var grouped = testList.GroupBy(item=> item.stock);
var eachStock = grouped.Select(c => string.Join(" ", c.Key, string.Join(", ", c.Select(x => x.price))));

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, eachStock));
```

That will do exactly what you have written, within reason. I doubt you actually want to do the string manipulation stuff, but I put that in there so that you can see the results easily before you say you need the `Where` clause again.

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see what you want, but if you only want to iterate try this:

```
var groups = testList.GroupBy(item=> item.stock);
foreach (var group in groups) // get the individual groups
{
  Console.Write(group.Key); // Will print "StocksFR1:" etc
  // well, I wont pretty print, up to you :)
  foreach (var item in group)
  {
    Console.Write(item.price); // Will print the price
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Remember that `GroupBy` doesn't return a group, it returns a set of groups!